# Reviewer badge - why does the value get changed to much less so often?

Tags: discussion, review, badges, badge-progress

For months I had over 150-160 reviews shown in my progress for Reviewer badge. In recent days it got rewinded multiple time reaching values of 10, 16 and 20. I guess I don't understand something when it comes to review queues so I would like some pointers what is going on here. If progress gets reset every once in a while why doesn't it reset to 0 (I had days when I hadn't reviewed any material on SO yet the progress remained)? I'm not a badge grinder and frankly I use the review indicator as a nice overview how much I've done so far (current day, week etc.). I'm just interested what is going on here?

Comment: Are you sure you were looking at the same queue each time? "Review badges are awarded once per review queue. "

Comment: You are absolutely right. Now that I have switched between the queues I see that the number is changing accordingly. It's still weird because I can swear that in one of the queues I had more than 160-170 reviews (the number of the queue was showing me that) but now the highest number I have is 137.